# Tensorflow AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to save a model for  Plant Diseases Detection as a tf file.

But it stuck at AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Here is a part of the code:

```
# Install nightly package for some functionalities that aren't in alpha
!pip install tf-nightly

# Install TF Hub for TF2
!pip install 'tensorflow-hub == 0.4'
```

```
import time
t = time.time()

export_path = "/tmp/saved_models/{}".format(int(t))
#tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, export_path)
model.save(
    model,
    export_path
)


export_path
```

It stuck here

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-51-821d8bfb0d93> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 export_path = "/tmp/saved_models/{}".format(int(t))
      5 #tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, export_path)
----> 6 model.save(
      7     model,
      8     export_path

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/legacy/saving_utils.py in is_hdf5_filepath(filepath)
    366 def is_hdf5_filepath(filepath):
    367     return (
--> 368         filepath.endswith(".h5")
    369         or filepath.endswith(".keras")
    370         or filepath.endswith(".hdf5")

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Here is the link to the collab notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1emOw4jhOZxMKZjGfZ_qRMk1KBqh6CNpv#scrollTo=JRrsFKez6fFf

I have search and try a lot of different thing but nothing work.

Have you a solution for that?

Wish you a beautiful day ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to [`model.save()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save) is documented to be `filepath`, but you are passing `model`.

Change

```
model.save(
    model,
    export_path
)
```

to

```
model.save(export_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this a version issue but I guess you can bypass this by setting a filetype for your saved model, e.g.:

```
export_path = "/tmp/saved_models/{}.h5".format(int(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help Steven and Ioannis ;-)

Here is the final code that work:

```
import time
t = time.time()
export_path = "/tmp/saved_models/{}.h5".format(int(t))
model.save(export_path)
export_path
```